# How do I truncate a part of the string in Java?

Tags: java, string, substring

In my test I want to validate the system Datetime and zone when I get a particular response. However due to the fact that there is a slight delay between when the response is generated by system and when the validation in the test takes place, it fails.

The Datetime of response is (e.g.) - 2019-08-09T09:02:30.836+10:00

The test validation takes place at (e.g.) - 2019-08-09T09:02:30.956+10:00

How do I remove the milliseconds bit if possible or anything after "2:30"

Comment: It won't help to remove the milliseconds if the response is at 2:30.999 and the validation is a millisecond later. What you need to do is get the difference and validate that it's below some acceptable threshold, e.g., 1 second.

Comment: Compute the difference and test if it’s within a certain range.

Comment: I see, so in that case any idea how can I do I compute the difference?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can parse the String to ZonedDateTime, then set the nanoseconds to 0 and compare.

```java
        ZonedDateTime first = ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-08-09T09:02:30.836+10:00").withNano(0);

        ZonedDateTime second = ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-08-09T09:02:30.956+10:00").withNano(0);

        boolean datesEqual = first.isEqual(second);
```

This is how you can parse the String to ZonedDateTime and check if the two values are within some maximum duration, for example 1 second.

```java
        ZonedDateTime first = ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-08-09T09:02:30.836+10:00");

        ZonedDateTime second = ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-08-09T09:02:30.956+10:00");

        Duration duration = Duration.between(first, second);

        Duration maximumDuration = Duration.ofSeconds(1);

        boolean withinDuration = duration.minus(maximumDuration).isNegative();
```

Comment: This would be unequal if the `second` portions rolls over to the next second. The times could only be a couple of `ms` different.

Comment: Yeah which is what the user is trying to accomplish. He doesn't care about milliseconds, just the seconds.

Comment: see @shmosel comment above.

Comment: Okay, I understand why the user might want to check if the dates are within some threshold. That being said, this isn't what the user wanted, it's just speculation. Nonetheless, i'll update this.

Comment: Nice answer, I am guessing that the OP did not really know what he wanted, but you have shown him a nice way to do it.